# Shift location of NSSheets down by 23 pixels

Tags: cocoa, nswindow

I have a window with none of the OS-provided window design, but a title bar that is based off of an NSView. This is not an issue until I want to display a sheet - the sheet comes out of the first line of pixels of the window, and not under the title bar, how they should be. (I expected this, to be honest.)

The real question here is this - how can I get the sheets to start out 23 pixels from the top of the window, if possible at all? If not possible, what alternatives would there be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement this `NSWindowDelegate` method:

```
- (NSRect)window:(NSWindow *)window willPositionSheet:(NSWindow *)sheet usingRect:(NSRect)rect
```

Comment: So, I would just put this into my NSWindow class's code, and define it in the header file, or would I need to make a new class for just this?

Comment: Never mind, I noticed that I had to set [self setDelegate:self] for it to work. Thanks!